# What is the difference between "cierra" and "cierro"?

Tags: gramática

In my Spanish text book, it gives the following examples:

```
Cierra los lunes = It closes on Mondays
Cierro la puerta = I’m closing the door
```

What is the difference between `Cierra` and `Cierro`? At first I thought they may be the masculine and feminine versions of Cerrar. But then the examples wouldn't work, as `days of the week` are masculine and `door` is feminine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spanish verb tenses do not differentiate between masculine and feminine, except for the participe and only when it acts as an adjective.

The difference between *cierro* and *cierra* is just the subject that does the action. The present indicative of verb *cerrar* is:

```
Yo           cierro
Tú           cierras
Él/ella/ello cierra
Nosotros/as  cerramos
Vosotros/as  cerráis
Ellos/as     cierran
```

So in *cierro* the subject is the first person singular, whereas in *cierra* the subject is the third person singular.

Comment: Yes, third person singular, like (la tienda) cierra los lunes, or (el negocio) cierra los lunes. Some subject that is implicit in the sentence.